# Error "Server Error Error: No "exports" main defined in C:\chart\node_modules\chart.js\package.json"

Tags: next.js, react-chartjs, date-fns

I am trying to get the time scale (x-axis) using `chartjs-adapter-date-fns` adapter and getting this error:

> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\chart\node_modules\chart.js\package.json when using "import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns" in Next.js'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/issues/59) that currently exists with the `chartjs-adapter-date-fns` adapter in combination with `chart.js@4.0.1`. The [Luxon](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon) adapter has already released a [fix](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon/pull/77) for this issue which makes it work with `chart.js@4.0.1`.

Until it is fixed, you could use the [Luxon](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon) adapter instead:

```bash
npm install luxon chartjs-adapter-luxon --save
```

```
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';
```